# Needing some help with two errors (C++)

Tags: c++, class, templates, syntax, multiple-inheritance

Ive been up for a while coding and it is probably an easy mistake that im just overlooking from lack of sleep, but the problem happens with this segment of code.

```
do
{
    aWithIntAcct.enterAccountData();
    aWithIntAcct.getSavInfo();
    aWithIntAcct.getCheckingInfo();
    checkAcct.push_back(aWithIntAcct);
    cout << "Would you like to enter another Checking Account with interest? y or n ";
    cin >> quitChar;
}while(quitChar != QUIT);
```

it says that I have ambiguous access of 'enterAccountData' (Error C2385) 
This is contradictory to the other (Error C3861) identifier not found.

My Classes are inherited so im not sure why this inst working for me. Any suggestions?

REST OF CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
void repeatValue(T val, int times)
{
for(int x = 0; x < times; x++)
{
    cout << "-";
}
};
template <class T>
void produceReport(int tableRows, string title, T acctType)
{
cout << tableRows << endl;
cout << title << endl;
cout << acctType;
};

class BankAccount
{
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const BankAccount&);
friend istream& operator>>(istream&, BankAccount&);
private:
int acctNum;
double acctBal;
public:
BankAccount(int = 0,double = 0.0);

double operator+=(BankAccount);
int operator+(BankAccount);
friend bool operator>(BankAccount &acctBalOne, BankAccount &acctBalTwo);
friend bool operator<(BankAccount &acctBalOne, BankAccount &acctBalTwo);
int operator==(const BankAccount acctNumOne);
void enterAccountData();
void displayAccount();
void setAcctNum(int);
void setAcctBal(double);
int getAcctNum();
double getAcctBal();
};
BankAccount::BankAccount(int num, double bal)
{
acctNum = num;
acctBal = bal;
}
double BankAccount::operator+=(BankAccount bankAcct)
{
acctBal += acctBal + bankAcct.acctBal;
return acctBal;
}
int BankAccount::operator+(BankAccount newAcctNum)
{
const int INCREMENT = 1;
newAcctNum.acctNum = acctNum + INCREMENT;
return newAcctNum.acctNum;
}
bool operator>(BankAccount &acctBalOne, BankAccount &acctBalTwo)
{
return acctBalOne.acctBal > acctBalTwo.acctBal;
}
bool operator<(BankAccount &acctBalOne, BankAccount &acctBalTwo)
{
return acctBalOne.acctBal < acctBalTwo.acctBal;
}
int BankAccount::operator== (const BankAccount acctNumOne)
{
int truth = 0;
if(acctNum == acctNumOne.acctNum)
    truth = 1;
return truth;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& display, const BankAccount& aAcct)
{
display << "Account #" << aAcct.acctNum << endl;
display << "Account Balance $" << aAcct.acctBal << endl;
return display;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& dataIn, BankAccount& aAcct)
{
cout << endl << "Enter in an Account # ";
dataIn >> aAcct.acctNum;
cout << "Enter in an Account Balance $ ";
dataIn >> aAcct.acctBal;
return dataIn;
}
void BankAccount::enterAccountData()
{
cout << "Enter the Account:#";
cin >> acctNum;
cout << endl << "Enter the Account Balance:$";
cin >> acctBal;
}
void BankAccount::displayAccount()
{
cout << "The Account number is #" << acctNum << endl;
cout << "The Account Balance is $" << acctBal << endl;
}
void BankAccount::setAcctNum(int num)
{
acctNum = num;
}
void BankAccount::setAcctBal(double bal)
{
acctBal = bal;
}
int BankAccount::getAcctNum()
{
return acctNum;
}
double BankAccount::getAcctBal()
{
return acctBal;
}
class SavingsAccount : public BankAccount
{
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const SavingsAccount&);
private:
double interest;
public:
SavingsAccount(double = 0.0);
void displaySavAccount();
void getSavInfo();
};
SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(double intRate)
{
interest = intRate;
}
void SavingsAccount::getSavInfo()
{
cout << "Enter Interest Rate: ";
cin >> interest;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& display, SavingsAccount& aSavAcct)
{
aSavAcct.displaySavAccount();
return display;
}
void SavingsAccount::displaySavAccount()
{
cout << "     Savings information.     " << endl;
cout << "Interest Rate on the account is:" << interest << endl;
}
class CheckingAccount : public BankAccount
{
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& display, const CheckingAccount& aCheckAcct);
private:
double monthlyFee;
int checksAllowed;
public:
CheckingAccount(double = 0,int = 0,int = 0,double = 0);
void displayCheckAccount();
void getCheckingInfo();
};
CheckingAccount::CheckingAccount(double fee, int allowed, int num, double bal) :      BankAccount(num,bal), monthlyFee(fee), checksAllowed(allowed)
{

}
void CheckingAccount::getCheckingInfo()
{
cout << "Enter monthly fee of the Account for the checking account. $";
cin >> monthlyFee;
cout << endl << "How many checks are allowed?" << endl;
cin >> checksAllowed;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& display, CheckingAccount& aCheckAcct)
{
aCheckAcct.displayCheckAccount();
return display;
}
void CheckingAccount::displayCheckAccount()
{
cout << "           Checking Information           " << endl;
BankAccount::displayAccount();
cout << "Monthly fee on the account is:$" << monthlyFee << endl;
cout << "Checks allowed for this account is: " << checksAllowed << endl;
}
class CheckingWithInterest : public SavingsAccount, public CheckingAccount
{
private:

public:
CheckingWithInterest();
void displayWithInterest();
};
CheckingWithInterest::CheckingWithInterest() : CheckingAccount(0,0,9999,0), SavingsAccount(0.03)
{}
void CheckingWithInterest::displayWithInterest()
{
CheckingAccount::displayCheckAccount();
SavingsAccount::displaySavAccount();
}
int main()
{
cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

unsigned count;
vector<SavingsAccount>savAcct;
SavingsAccount aSavAcct;
vector<CheckingAccount>checkAcct;
CheckingAccount aCheckAcct;
vector<CheckingWithInterest>withIntAcct;
CheckingWithInterest aWithIntAcct;
const char QUIT = 'n';
char quitChar = 'y';
cout << "Do you want to enter Savings Information? y or n ";
cin >> quitChar;
do
{
    aSavAcct.enterAccountData();
    aSavAcct.getSavInfo();
    savAcct.push_back(aSavAcct);
    cout << "Would you like to enter another Savings Account? y or n ";
    cin >> quitChar;
}while(quitChar != QUIT);
cout << "Do you want to enter Checking Information? y or n ";
cin >> quitChar;
do
{
    aCheckAcct.enterAccountData();
    aCheckAcct.getCheckingInfo();
    checkAcct.push_back(aCheckAcct);
    cout << "Would you like to enter another Checking Account? y or n ";
    cin >> quitChar;
}while(quitChar != QUIT);
cout << "Do you want to enter Checking with interest account Information? y or n ";
cin >> quitChar;
do
{
    aWithIntAcct.enterAccountData(); // error points here for both (Line 233)
    aWithIntAcct.getSavInfo();
    aWithIntAcct.getCheckingInfo();
    checkAcct.push_back(aWithIntAcct);
    cout << "Would you like to enter another Checking Account with interest? y or n ";
    cin >> quitChar;
}while(quitChar != QUIT);

sort(savAcct.begin(), savAcct.end());
for(count = 0; count < savAcct.size(); ++count)
{
    repeatValue(savAcct.at(count), count);
    cout << endl;
    produceReport(savAcct.size(), "Savings Account Information", savAcct.at(count));
}
sort(checkAcct.begin(), checkAcct.end());
for(count = 0; count < checkAcct.size(); ++count)
{
    repeatValue(checkAcct.at(count), count);
    cout << endl;
    produceReport(checkAcct.size(), "Checking Account Information", checkAcct.at(count));
}
sort(withIntAcct.begin(), withIntAcct.end());
for(count = 0; count < withIntAcct.size(); ++count)
{
    repeatValue(withIntAcct.at(count), count);
    cout << endl;
    produceReport(withIntAcct.size(), "Checking with interest Account Information",      withIntAcct.at(count));
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
class BankAccount
class SavingsAccount : public BankAccount
class CheckingAccount : public BankAccount
class CheckingWithInterest : public SavingsAccount, public CheckingAccount
```

This inheritance hierarchy is (probably) incorrect.  Right now it looks like this:

```
 BankAccount       BankAccount
      |                 |
SavingsAccount   CheckingAccount
      \                 /
      CheckingWithInterest
```

So, each `CheckingWithInterest` object actually has *two* `BankAccount` base class subobjects:  one from its `SavingsAccount` base class subobject and one from its `CheckingAccount` base class subobject.

So, when you try to call a `BankAccount` member function on a `CheckingWithInterest` object, e.g.,

```
CheckingWithInterest account;
account.enterAccountData();
```

the compiler doesn't know whether you mean the `enterAccountData()` from the `BankAccount` that is part of the `SavingsAccount` base class or you mean the `enterAccountData()` from the `BankAccount` that is part of the `CheckingAccount` base class.

I'm not sure what, exactly, your requirements are, but if you only want to have a single `BankAccount` base class subobject, you probably need to use virtual inheritance when you derive `CheckingAccount` and `SavingsAccount` from `BankAccount`, so that the `BankAccount` subobject is shared between them when they are composed in `CheckingWithInterest`:

```
class BankAccount
class SavingsAccount : public virtual BankAccount
class CheckingAccount : public virtual BankAccount
class CheckingWithInterest : public SavingsAccount, public CheckingAccount
```

If you really do want there to be two `BankAccount` base class subobjects, then when you call `enterAccountData()`, you need to qualify on which base class subobject you want to call the member function:

```
account.CheckingAccount::enterAccountData();
```

Comment: It would be also good if you mention that the base class needs to be initialized explicitly, by calling its constructor in the initializer list of `CheckingWithInterest`.

Comment: `BankAccount` has a default constructor; explicit initialization is not necessary.  If the OP does want to initialize the virtual base class using a non-default constructor, then yes, only the most derived class calls constructors for virtual base class subobjects.

Comment: Ohh I see... I didn't notice that `BankAccount` has default constructor.

Comment: I changed the two Values and it still gave me the same two errors. I had tried this before and it worked up till a certain point. Thats why the Bank account was derived publicly from both SavingsAccount and CheckingAccount.

Comment: Im sorry, you were correct. I actually forgot to change source code files from a previous file that was the predecessor to this one so i was loading something while looking at something else.... Thank you for helping me out and I kept it as Virtual and it runs great.